# hide console output from msbuild task

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildextensionpack

I am running this msbuild scriplet from command line (other details ommited)

```
<MSBuild Projects ="@(ProjectsToBuild)"
             ContinueOnError ="false"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
```

How can I hide its output if I don't have any errors on compile ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no parameters that you can add to a specific target in msbuild to get it to build without any command output. But you could wrap the call in a second target, then call the target by executing msbuild and using the /noconsolelogger flag:

```
<Exec Command="MSBuild $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(MsBuildThisFile) /t:TargetToExecute /nologo /noconsolelogger"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

msbuild output (mostly) comes from Logger objects. These objects are extensible; you can supply your own implementation, or you can use any of the built-in loggers.

If you're seeing console output from msbuild, you're seeing output from the built-in console logger. You can turn off the console logger using the `/noconsolelogger` command-line option.

Even with that option set, you'll still see a couple of lines of output: the startup message that includes the program name and the copyright message. You can suppress that output with the `/nologo` option.